# ¿Que diferencia hay entre estas dos? y ¿cual es mas segura?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, odbc

Entre estos 2 Codigos ¿cual es el mas seguro?

```
$query3 = odbc_prepare($conn, "Mi consulta SQL ?");             
odbc_execute($query2, array($variable));
```

O esta otra:

```
$query3 = odbc_prepare($conn, "Mi consulta SQL ?");             
$query2->bindParam(1, $variable, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query3->execute();
```

Si alguien es tan amable me indica la diferencia?

Comment: Ambas son seguras, la segunda es más específica, porque indica el tipo de datos, sin obligar al manejador a establecer esa característica.

Comment: Aunque, viendo el segundo código, parecería que en ese caso estás usando PDO combinado con odbc ¿? No sé qué resultados pueda dar eso, en el pasado ha habido problemas con esa mezcla, [como se reporta aquí](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/PHP-odbc-functions-vs-PDO-prepared-statement-acting-differently-with-ODBC-drivers). Nunca es bueno mezclar APIs o conectores en un mismo procedimiento, ni siquiera estilos de programación dentro de una misma API, te aconsejo que uses todo en odbc o todo en PDO, pero nunca mezclar. En cuanto a la seguridad, ambas formas serían seguras.

Comment: necesitare mas comentarios otra pregunta para las "INYECIONES" creas que esa sea mas segura que decir ¿esta? **$result =odbc_exec($conex,'consulta SQL Server');**

Comment: No entendí tu comentario. La *inyección* ocurre cuando dejas pasar datos externos directamente a ejecución, pues el peligro consiste en que un usuario mal intencionado puede modificar esos datos para construir una consulta peligrosa la cual se ejecutaría. Por tanto, si `consulta SQL Server` tiene datos proporcionados por el usuario es insegura y deberás usar consultas preparadas para prevenir el riesgo, pero si no tiene datos proporcionados por el usuario no hay ningún riesgo en mandarla a ejecutar directamente.

Comment: si hay un riesgo veras me han hecho varias veces **Shutdown** me diante inyecion de SQL server originando asi el apagado del servery otra vez tambien me pusieron **UPDATE table SET users = 'jodi**te', pass='jajajaja' ** por eso necesito saber lo mas que pueda de seguridad mira te hare una pregunta abajo que tambien es para cerrar y me gustaria saber la respuesta de otros Colegas.

Comment: Otra pregunta si llegan a hacer esto en un formulario con ganas de inyectar **"',"UPDATE TABLE SET point WHERE User ='ilegal'"*** ¿eso se evita en cual? ¿o es mejor que esta? **$resultado=odbc_exec($conex,consulta sql');** en la tabla ¿que se inserta? ¿la consulta es insertada? como este video el minuto 2:39 **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KafvnlaU08&ab_channel=TutorialesatuAlcance**

Comment: en el tercer comentario estoy preguntando si esa ¿tambien es segura? o ¿es la mas insegura de todas? esta consulta **$result =odbc_exec($conex,'consulta SQL Server');**

Comment: Creo haberte respondido: **cualquier consulta en la que algún dato provenga del exterior es insegura**. Ejemplo de consulta insegura: `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE elID=unValor` es insegura si `unValor` viene de un formulario, una URL, un archivo, etc por tanto esa consulta debe ser preparada. En cambio esta consulta no es insegura: `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE elID=1` porque el valor `1` está ya escrito en la consulta, no hay forma de manipularlo.  ¿Qué no entiendes de lo que vengo de explicarte?

Comment: Otra pregunta si llegan a hacer esto en un formulario con ganas de inyectar **"',"UPDATE TABLE SET point WHERE User ='ilegal'"*** ¿eso se evita en cual? ¿o es mejor que esta? **$resultado=odbc_exec($conex,consulta sql');** en la tabla ¿que se inserta? ¿la consulta es insertada asi **consulta como cadena de texto**? como este video el minuto 2:39 **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KafvnlaU08&ab_channel=TutorialesatuAlcance**

Comment: la ultima respuesta la entendi es que yo estoy mas enfocado en los formularios, pues lo estoy haciendo para un juego en linea y tambien quiero desarrollar un sitio web de envio de remesas y necesitare BUENOS habitos para evitar inyeciones a TODA COSTA

Comment: Es muy simple, como ya he dicho varias veces: cualquier consulta, de cualquier tipo, que maneje **datos externos**, debe ser preparada, no hay mayor misterio. El peligro de la inyección está en los datos externos, los cuales tú no controlas y que los hackers modifican para colar la inyección. La forma de neutralizar eso es preparar la consulta y pasar los datos aparte con el método *bind* o *execute* de la API / controlador que estés usando.